# Basic java: Guess the number binary search

Tags: java, binary-search

Alright, so the user thinks (does not type it) of a number between 1 and 10 (for example), the program prompts the user "Is you number less than or equal to X?", then the user types either true or false.
So far, I have managed to do the search interval, but I have no idea how to continue.
Main problem is, I am only allowed to use true of false, if I was allowed to use "correct!" then there will be no problem.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessTheNumber {

public static void main (String[]args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Think of a number between 1 and 10\n");

    double max = 10;
    double x = max/2;

    while (true){
        System.out.println("Is your number less than or equal to "+(int)x+" ?");
        String truth = scan.next();

        if(truth.equals("true")){
            x=x/2;
        }
        if(truth.equals("false")){
            x+=x/2;
        }
    }
    //The program breaks at some point
    System.out.println("Your number is: ");
 }
}
```

The program expects the user to type either true or false, so we can ignore anything else.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stuck on a java assignment, binary search algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711100/stuck-on-a-java-assignment-binary-search-algorithm)

Comment: Just to address the comment in the code:  no, the program does not break at some point.  In more specific terms - what are you asking about?  Do you need some *boolean* to specify whether or not you continue?  The program doesn't pick a number at random for you to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are not keeping track of the search interval, and you are not providing any way for the loop to end.  You will get an effectively infinite loop. You need to store the lower and upper bound, and modify them based on the user's input.

```
// ints, not doubles.  Do you expect 3.14159 as the user's choice?
int lower = 1;
int upper = 10;
int guess = (lower + upper) / 2;  // guess, not x. Make the name meaningful.
```

Then, when the user says that the guess is higher than the number he thought of, change the upper bound:

```
upper = guess - 1;
guess = (lower + upper) / 2;
```

Do something similar for the other case. It's your homework, not mine.

Finally, how do you know when you are done? What would indicate that?

```
if (/* we are done */) {
    break;
}
```

You may want another type of loop instead, or change `while(true)` to something else.  And, please don't do everything in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the beginning (inside) of your `while` loop:

```
System.out.println("Is your number " + x +" ?");
String truth = scan.next();
if(truth.equals("true")){
    break;
}
```

Other option: transform your `if` statements to look like the following:

```
if(truth.equals("true")){
    if(x == x/2) break;
    x=x/2;
}
if(truth.equals("false")){
    if(x == x + x/2) break;
    x+=x/2;
}
```

and then change the last output line to:

```
 System.out.println("Your number is: " + x);
```